# How to authenticate an user with only UserId or with UserId and Hased Password using Asp.net Identity in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

**Admin Module :**
Dashboard showing a list of all managers within admin's firm.

**Feature Required:**
Admin can authenticate itself as any of manager and can able to access all data assigned to that particular manager.

**Process:**
I am using Asp.net Identity.
I have only User Id and Hashed Password of Manager.

**Issue:**
How to authenticate an admin as a manager by using User Id or Hashed Password or Both.

Comment: Admin and Manager are roles. You should have a Roles table and a relationship table UserRole to perform authorization.

Comment: I have both roles and other required table, you haven't even got my point. I am able to login to any kind of user.

My problem is to make an admin user logged in to any of sub user by using sub roles credentials. As it is not possible to get the username and password (as Hashed or encrypted) to logged in sub-user from admin panel. I have the primary  key Guid of sub-user and I just want to know Is there any way to do it perfectly, i have done it by compromising with security by making another field for password and put UN-hashed password there for such kind of feature.

Comment: So basically you need a LoginAs functionality where in one user will login as another user. Is that correct? Yes it's possible.

Comment: of course, but i don't know the password of other user, i have only username and primary key of that user, How can it be achieved in asp.net identity ??

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain their Role as well

you have to check user role by userId then you have to show data as per role.

check couple link might be help you

[Custom-Permission-in-Object-Level](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/401015/Create-Custom-Permission-in-Object-Level/)

[authentication authorization user and role managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222974/authentication-authorization-user-and-role-managment-and-general-security-in/)